# Unsupported driver[] error when building docker image

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, .env

I am new to docker and I get the below error when trying to build my docker image. I want to containerise a php application using laravel framework and mysql as DB.

```
Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
#0 19.78 > @php artisan package:discover
    #0 19.86 In ConnectionFactory.php line 44:
    #0 19.86
    #0 19.86   Unsupported driver []
    #0 19.86
    #0 19.86
    #0 19.86 Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
# Use the default production configuration
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

COPY src/ /var/www/html/

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libzip-dev openssl zip unzip git
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring
RUN composer self-update




ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

I have a docker-compose.yml file which specifies mysql image:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  laravel-app:
    build:
      context: '.'
      args:
        uid: ${UID}
    container_name: laravel-app
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000
      - APACHE_RUN_GROUP=#1000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - app

  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-db
    volumes:
      - ./run/var:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - mysql-db

networks:
  backend:
    name: backend-network
```

Here is my .env file :

```
APP_NAME="myapp"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

#admin
DB_DRIVER=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="xxx"
DB_USERNAME="xxx"
DB_PASSWORD="xxx"

#feeds
FEEDS_DB_DRIVER=mysql
FEEDS_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
FEEDS_DB_PORT=3306
FEEDS_DB_DATABASE="xxx"
FEEDS_DB_USERNAME="xxx"
FEEDS_DB_PASSWORD="xxx"

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=xx
REDIS_PORT=xxxx

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=xxxx
MAIL_PORT=xxx
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Database.php file looks like below:

```
<?php

return [

  

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'admin'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => env('DB_DRIVER'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'feeds' => [
            'driver' => env('FEEDS_DB_DRIVER'),
            'host' => env('FEEDS_DB_HOST', ''),
            'port' => env('FEEDS_DB_PORT', ''),
            'database' => env('FEEDS_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('FEEDS_DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('FEEDS_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('FEEDS_DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried to use solutions provided in stackoverflow for similar issues, but it didnt help. The error remains still the same, in spite of any code modifications.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't put errors as image, just a block of inline text is much more readable. Thanks for the good amount of detail and formatting otherwise. I think your use of `php:apache` [containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) is incorrect and there should be a `CMD`.

Comment: Thanks I have edited the description. @danblack, could you please help to share more details?

Comment: `COPY src/ /var/www/html/` looks non-typical. is `src` the path of your Laravel project (relative to the Dockerfile) and does this include the .env file?

Comment: Many Thanks @apokryfos. Now, the error has disappeared. But there is another error : Could not open input file: artisan.  And yes, src is the folder where Laravel project is located, and Dockerfile is outside of this folder.

Comment: Also the error had disappeared when I placed the .env file inside the Laravel project folder . i.e. src

Comment: Is the `artisan` file also in src?

Comment: yes @apokryfos.

Comment: Now the error is resolved, but failing in database migration step. Getting error : Access denied for user 'feeds_user'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES) . However the first user present in .env file had no such error. Any idea to fix this one?